# Get file access permission of a specific user on a server in a different domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, file-server

In my environment, there are 2 domains connected via WAN link. Please look at the image below for the system topology:

[image]

I want to display the folder access permission of a user from one domain on a file server in the other domain. [I have referred to this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/171320/list-users-folder-access-permissions) and successfully exported the folder access permission of the user. The output was in a `.txt` file.

Is there any equal tool (like “SubInAcl”) or technique to display the folder access permission of a specific user on a server in a different domain? (In the case that the trust between both domain has been created and the user from one domain can access server in the other domain.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have correctly understood your question, thus can give the following solution for powershell:

`(Get-Acl "\\SERVER\share").Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like "Domain1\User"}`

Just replace `SERVER`, `Domain1` and `User` with your values.

You may easily store this as TextFile (using `Out-File` Cmdlet) or CSV (using `Export-Csv` Cmdlet).